# Using helper methods in ActionMailer mail definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use my `mailer_helper` methods in my `UserMailer` class. I've added `helper :mailer_helper` and that works great for the view files. However, they don't work in the actual mail definitions in UserMailer.rb.

For instance, I can't use a helper method when defining the mail subject:

```
mail(to: my_email,
    reply_to: someones_email,
     subject: "#{helper_method "something"}: Hello!")
```

How can I get that working?

## NOTE

This may seem similar to a question I asked recently, but it's completely different. In this question, I'm asking about using helper methods that are defined in a helper file that I I'm already successfully using in the mailer views. The other question is about using helper methods defined in a controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manuelly include your helper in the ActionMailer class you have.

```
class UserMailer
  include YourHelper

  #here you can use the method of your helper
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get `undefined method 'mymethod' for MailHelper:Module`